# Big-O complexity of algorithm

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

Whats the total BigO complexity of an algorithm like the one below:

```
function void a(int n, int p) {
    for(i = 0; id < n; i++){
        print(i)
        for(j=0; j < p; j++){
            print(i+j)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on...(input length, input value...)? What´s your guess?

Comment: I mean if the input is n for first loop and p for second loop , the total complexity is O(n+p) or O(n*p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it´s the value instead of (logarithmic) length.
If i have n=5 and p=10, how much prints would this give?
50. This means n*p is correct

Comment: If one of the loops were logarithmic(for example p), wouldnt the BigO notation be O(n*logp)

Comment: Yes, but it isn´t log. A log. loop for p would loop something like 1 time for p 1-9, 2 time for 10-99, 3 time for 100-999 and so on

Answer (score 1):

A formal and efficient way is to use the following methodology:

[image]

Where `c` is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it... you do `n` times `p` loops. So `O(n*p)`.